# Merging all the loose parts in an STL file

Tags: modeling

I'd like to cut a model imported from STL into two. However, the model consists of thousands of small loose components, which cause unexpected behavior after applying the "Bisect" tool. Is there any way to merge all of them (or compute the union) to have one object without any loose components?

[image]